# How to print this collections.defaultdict in descending order in python?

Tags: python, collections, defaultdict

I am counting the frequencies of addresses from a csv file, and then printing the address and the counts. The csv file contains many fields so I choose only the fields I need.

Unfortunately, the printing happens unordered.
How can I print it in descending order?

Below is the simplified code. I'm also using a set (owners) but I've removed the code related to it to keep the question simple.

```
import csv
import collections 

multiOwner = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {'freq': 0, 'owners': set()})

with open('input.csv', newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for folio,owner1,owner2,address, *rest in csv_reader:
        multiOwner[address]['freq'] += 1
        
    for address in multiOwner:
        print (address,multiOwner[address]['freq'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `SortedDict` from the `SortedContainers` library. It's easy to use, written in pure Python, and surprisingly efficient. However I don't think they offer a `SortedDefaultDict`.

Otherwise you can extract a sorted list of the keys and iterate over that list:

```
keys=sorted(list(multiOwner.keys()), key=lambda x:multiOwner[x]['freq'], reverse=True)
for k in keys:
    print(k, multiOwner[k]['freq'])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I get an invalid syntax error pointing to the x -    

 keys=sorted(list(multiOwner.keys()), key=lamdba x:multiOwner[x]['freq'], reverse=True)
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry I wrote lamdba instead of lambda :(. Editing the answer

Comment: thanks I would have never seen that, it works now :)